# how to disable a check box using java script conditionally

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have 3 check boxes in 3 different pages,i want to check one check box at time means at first all 3 are unchecked and if i checked one check box remaining 2 check boxes should be disable.

each check box value i am storing in 3 different text file using array in the form of 1's and 0's.
now for one page i am reading check box values and based condition trying to disable check box but its not working.

I have Tried this

check box html code:

```
input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="check[0]" value="1" />
```

java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var cb1 =document.getElementById("cb1");
var cb2 = "<?php echo $cb2_arr[5] ?>" ; //cb2=1 or 0
var cb3 = "<?php echo $cb3_arr[6] ?>"; //cb3=1 or 0

if(cb2 ==1 || cb3 == 1){
cb1.disabled = true;
}else{
cb1.disabled = false;
}
</script>
```

cb1.disabled = true; for me its not working i kept alert statements above and below it ,only above one is displayed

Please help me how to set disabled property, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check `input1.value == ""`, not simply `input1 == ""`

You also need to fire your method originally, and also run it every time your select lists change value.

Give the function a name

```
function setCheckState(evt) {
    if (input1.value == "" || input2.value == "") {
        result.disabled = true;
    } else {
        result.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Add event listeners

```
input1.addEventListener('change', setCheckState);
input2.addEventListener('change', setCheckState);
// Fire the method to get the initial checkbox state set

setCheckState();
```

Finally, you can reduce your if() statement to a simple assignment...

```
function setCheckState(evt) {
    result.disabled = input1.value == "" || input2.value == "";
}
```

Comment: input1.addEventListener('change', setCheckState);
input2.addEventListener('change', setCheckState);

i have cb2=1,cb3=1

i am not reading check boxes id ,you want to try like this
cb2.addEventListener('change', setCheckState); //cb2 is 1 or 0 but not reading an id
cb3.addEventListener('change', setCheckState);//cb3 is 1 or 0 but not reading an id

Answer (score 1):

try this to disabled and remove disabled,

```
 if ($('#cb3').is(':checked') || $('#cb2').is(':checked')) {
         $('#cb1').setAttribute('disabled', true);
}else{
         $('#cb1').setAttribute('disabled', false);
}
```

Comment: thanks bro ,cb2 and cb3 not in same .php file bro , 3 check boxes in 3 different page like cb1 in page1.php cb2 in page2.php .... am storing cb1 in cb1.txt ,cb2 vale in cb22.txt and cb3 value in cb3.txt by using other 2 check box value remaing check box shoul be disable.